# Do DNS messages pad names to an even number of bytes?

Tags: dns, rfc, rfc1035

**Preliminary note**

> Yes, I am aware of the existence of DNS libraries and easy-to-use DNS servers. I am doing this purely for academic purposes, and to get a grasp of how DNS queries work.

**The question**

I was looking at [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) to get an idea of how DNS messages work. I think I more or less understood everything in that memo. There is one thing that I can't interpret autonomously, however. If you look at Section 4.1.3, here is how the resource record format is described:

```
                                   1  1  1  1  1  1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
   |                                               |
   /                                               /
   /                      NAME                     /
   |                                               |
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
   |                      TYPE                     |
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
   |                     CLASS                     |
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
   |                      TTL                      |
   |                                               |
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
   |                   RDLENGTH                    |
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
   /                     RDATA                     /
   /                                               /
   +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

In this scheme, `NAME` ends at the end of a two-bytes block. Does this mean that its length in bytes should always be a multiple of two? The format for names is described earlier in the RFC as a sequence of labels, terminated by a zero-length label. This means that, depending on the name, its length can arbitrarily be even or odd. So does `NAME` need padding to an even number of bytes? And if so, how should I pad?

I would have ignored the issue and assumed that no padding is required, if it wasn't that in Section 4.1.1 it specifies that `QNAME` does not need padding. Since they didn't specify the same for `NAME` in the answer RRs, I was wondering if I should assume that there is some difference.

Comment: `//` in the ASCII art diagram means "undefined" length. But any given name starts with 2 bytes that encode either the length of next parts or a pointer. This is explained later, in 4.1.4 in the RFC in fact, which makes it difficult to read indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no padding. If you have doubt, capture a query about the root zone (the name of which is a single NULL octet, so an odd length) from a root server (they can be trusted to get the protocol right as it is used in the real world) and look at it.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was hoping for! :)